# IDEs that can rename JS functions that have the same name as functions on other classes

Tags: javascript, ide, refactoring

I'm wondering if anyone knows of an IDE that has refactoring tools such as "rename function" or "find all references" that are not confused by two functions with the same name on different classes.

That is, if you had a class Foo with Foo.prototype.myFunc and a class Bar with Bar.prototype.myFunc I'd want to be able to right-click on a call like

```
var b = new Bar();
b.myFunc();
```

and have it provide refactoring tools that would only apply to Bar.myFunc() and not Foo.myFunc().

Answer (score 0):

The combination of Visual Studio and JetBrains ReSharper provides a number of intelligent [JavaScript refactoring](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/ReSharper_by_Language__JavaScript__Refactorings.html) tools, which should be able to do this: